# Color specification in \indexmarkstyle for \showindexmarks leaks into body text

Tags: color, memoir, makeindex

The following source file `test.tex` is OK:

```
% file test.tex
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\makeindex
% OK:
\indexmarkstyle{\normalfont\small\sffamily}
% Not OK: it colors text itself:
%\indexmarkstyle{\normalfont\small\sffamily\color{red}}
\showindexmarks

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{We begin}

Hello\index{Hello} to the World\index{World}!

\bigskip
abc \index{alphabet!abc} is before def.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

We'll use the index style file:

```
% file test.ist
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\medskip\\hfill\\large\\textsf{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\hfill}\\medskip\\nopagebreak\n"
```

However, if I try to color the index items displayed in the margin by `\showindexmarks` — by commenting out the first `\indexmarkstyle` line and uncommenting the second one, the one that includes `\color{red}` — then:

- those displayed marginal index items colored red, as desired; *but*
- so is some of the body text near the `\index` expressions, as well as entire the chapter title, which is *not* wanted, of course.

See the output for that chapter:

[image: Color leaks from \indexmarkstyle into text.]

**How can that color leak into the body text be avoided?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by making sure the index mark style and index marks are within a group, which isn't done by default.

`memoir` seems to often put `\normalfont\normalsize` everywhere so the font doesn't impact too much beyond the index marks. But there's not so many calls to `\normalcolor`.

Add this to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@showidx}[1]{%
  \insert\@indexbox{%
    \begingroup% add begin group
    \@sanitizeat
    \the\indexmarkstyle
    \hsize\marginparwidth
    \hangindent\marginparsep \parindent\z@
    \everypar{}\let\par\@@par \parfillskip\@flushglue
    \lineskip\normallineskip
    \baselineskip .8\normalbaselineskip\sloppy
    \raggedright \leavevmode
    \vrule \@height .7\normalbaselineskip \@width \z@\relax
      #1\relax
    \vrule \@height \z@ \@depth .3\normalbaselineskip \@width \z@\relax
    \endgroup% add end group
  }%
  \ifhmode\penalty\@M \hskip\z@skip\fi}
\makeatother
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\makeindex
% OK:
\indexmarkstyle{\normalfont\small\sffamily}
% Not OK: it colors text itself:
\indexmarkstyle{\normalfont\small\sffamily\color{red}}
\showindexmarks

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@showidx}[1]{%
  \insert\@indexbox{%
    \begingroup% add begin group
    \@sanitizeat
    \the\indexmarkstyle
    \hsize\marginparwidth
    \hangindent\marginparsep \parindent\z@
    \everypar{}\let\par\@@par \parfillskip\@flushglue
    \lineskip\normallineskip
    \baselineskip .8\normalbaselineskip\sloppy
    \raggedright \leavevmode
    \vrule \@height .7\normalbaselineskip \@width \z@\relax
      #1\relax
    \vrule \@height \z@ \@depth .3\normalbaselineskip \@width \z@\relax
    \endgroup% add end group
  }%
  \ifhmode\penalty\@M \hskip\z@skip\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{We begin}

Hello\index{Hello} to the World\index{World}!

\bigskip
abc \index{alphabet!abc} is before def.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]